# Overwriting the parquet file throws exception in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hdfs

I am trying to read the parquet file from hdfs location, do some transformations and overwrite the file in the same location. I had to overwrite the file in the same location because I had to run the same code multiple times.

Here is the code I have written

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").parquet("hdfs://master:8020/persist/local/")
//after applying some transformations lets say the final dataframe is transDF which I want to overwrite at the same location.
transDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("hdfs://master:8020/persist/local/")
```

Now the problem is before reading the parquet file from the given location, spark for some reason I believe it deletes the file at the given location because of overwrite mode. So when executing the code I get the following error.

```
File does not exist: hdfs://master:8020/persist/local/part-00000-e73c4dfd-d008-4007-8274-d445bdea3fc8-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour while do Overwrite to parquet hive tables. I tried change settings for parquet metastore, caching, etc.. but no luck. The only solution that worked for me it was just save existing data to stage location. Then drop the original location and save new data in "Ignore" mode. Hopefully someobdy will come with better solution

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is that you cannot overwrite what you are reading. The reason behind this is that overwrite would need to delete everything, however, since spark is working in parallel, some portions might still be reading at the time. Furthermore, even if everything was read, spark needs the original file to recalculate tasks which are failed.

Since you need the input for multiple iterations, I would simply make the name of the input and the output into arguments for the function that does one iteration and delete the previous iteration only once the writing is successful.

Comment: This is the answer I was searching for. Originally, I was partitioning my data into s3. I had switched to not use partitioning, and started facing `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileDownloadException` after reading and attempting to write back to the same s3 bucket.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have tried and it worked. My requirement was almost same. It was upsert option.

by the way, spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic') property was set. Even then also the Transform job was failing

1. Took a backup of S3 folder (final curated layer) before every batch operation
2. using the dataframe operations, first delete the S3 parquet file location before overwrite
3. then Append to the particular location

Previously the entire job was running for 1.5Hrs and failing frequently. Now it's taking 10-15mins for the entire operations